# Conectar a Xampp desde netbeans en MAC

Tags: netbeans, xampp, macos

estoy realizando un proyecto en netbeans y a la hora de conectar el servidor MYSQL me dice que debo poner un "path" o "url" en admin properties para realizar la conexión. El problema es que no estoy segura que archivo poner ahí, ya que cuando descargué xampp no me creo una carpeta con los archivos, solo descargó la aplicación. 
Todo esto desde Mac (que le agrega mil complicaciones por si solo).
Si no se entendió o se necesitan más detalles no tengo problemas en darlos, pero por favor necesito ayuda!.
Gracias de antemano!!!!!!![image: ![The path to the MYSQL start is not set]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olt9b.png)

Comment: Hola, varias dudas: ¿Cómo creas la conexión a MySQL desde Netbeans? ¿Te solicita algún Driver? ¿No muestra las bd existentes o no te muestra absolutamente nada? ¿Has instalado MySQL a parte o en conjunto con XAMPP?

Comment: seria bueno que incluyas algo de código relacionado a los archivos que estas usando para la conexión... o algunos detalles que sean de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Mac no agrega complicaciones, mas bien no lo sabes usar. MAC OS X ya trae instalado un apache en el sistema operativo es por eso que xampp no te instala archivos. MAC OS X no trae MySQL ese si lo tienes que instalar. Pero debido a todo eso la versión de xampp para mac solo funciona como un control de interfaz gráfica. En las configuraciones de XAMPP le tienes que decir donde esta el ejecutable de apache para que lo levante. También ocurre con mysql, por eso te marca ese error, porque no sabe donde esta mysql. Recuerda que MAC OS X es un unix y... como levantas apache y mysql en unix??? Por ejemplo Linux: la respuesta es que se levantan por linea de comandos.

El XAMPP de MAC te ahorra el tener que levantarlos por linea de comandos. Solo los configuras y los puedes levantar por modo gráfico. Te dejo esta liga para que sepas donde esta el [apache por defecto en MAC OS X](https://www.mkyong.com/mac/mac-osx-where-is-default-localhost-folder/). Esto no quiere decir que tengas que usar ese apache forzosamente puedes instalar tu propio apache (mas recomendable porque esta mas actualizado) y configurarlo con XAMPP. Recuerda XAMPP en MAC solo funciona como control gráfico.

Por ultimo, para que funcione con netbeans yo lo que hice fue hacer mi carpeta del workspace en htdocs y asi todo se publica inmediatamente. Solo le das run en netbeans y carga todo facilmente, si es que apache esta corriendo. Si instalas otro apache recuerda no encimar los puertos.

Ahora XAMPP si te instala un apache pero esta dentro de la app. Ahi es donde tienes que apuntar la configuración. [Mira la 1er pregunta](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/faq_osx.html).